# Добавить дополнительные value в option при заданном условии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

Необходимо добавить ещё два `<option>` в "sel", при выборе в "connectid" value="7". Чтобы только тогда появлялись два дополнительных `<option>`.

HTML:

```
<select id="connectid" name="conectId">
   <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
   <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
   <option value="4">ПОСЕЩЕНИЕ</option>
   <option value="5">ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛЬ</option>
   <option value="6">ПОЧТА</option>
   <option value="7">ГОРЯЧАЯ ЛИНИЯ</option>
   <option value="9">ЛИЧНЫЙ ПРИЁМ</option>
</select>

...

<select id="sel" name="username" onclick="numberone()" style="display: block;">
    <option value="0">Назначить</option>
    <option value="И1">ИНГОССТРАХ</option>
        <option value="Р1">Р1</option>
        <option value="С1">С1</option>
        <option value="Т1">Т1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Примером как это можно реализовать.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("sel");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "K2";
x.add(option);

Comment: Еще вопросы есть?

Comment: Спасибо, принцип добавления понятен

Comment: Что наподобие такого как написать var x = $( "#sel option:selected" ).К2(); можно написать?

Comment: немного по-другому https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Что то я вставляю код и при каждом выборе удваивается потом дальше удваивается var x = document.getElementById("sel"); 
                var option = document.createElement("option"); 
                option.text = "K2"; 
                x.add(option);

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS.

```js
var oSelect1st = document.querySelector('#connectid');
var oSelect2nd = document.querySelector('#sel');
var oOpt1st, oOpt2nd;
oSelect1st.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == '7') {
    oOpt1st = document.createElement('OPTION');
    oOpt2nd = document.createElement('OPTION');
    oOpt1st.value = 'С1'; oOpt1st.text = 'С1';
    oOpt2nd.value = 'Т1'; oOpt2nd.text = 'Т1';
    oSelect2nd.appendChild(oOpt1st);
    oSelect2nd.appendChild(oOpt2nd);
  } else if (oOpt1st && oOpt2nd) {
    oSelect2nd.selectedIndex = 0;
    oOpt1st.remove();
    oOpt2nd.remove();
  };
});
```

```html
<select id="connectid" name="conectId">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
  <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
  <option value="4">ПОСЕЩЕНИЕ</option>
  <option value="5">ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛЬ</option>
  <option value="6">ПОЧТА</option>
  <option value="7">ГОРЯЧАЯ ЛИНИЯ</option>
  <option value="9">ЛИЧНЫЙ ПРИЁМ</option>
</select>

<select id="sel" name="username" style="display: block;">
  <option value="0">Назначить</option>
  <option value="И1">ИНГОССТРАХ</option>
  <option value="Р1">Р1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, круто работает

Comment: @dmr рад, что помогло. Вообще, в таких специальных формах не приветствуется динамическое удаление/добавление. Обычно, все пункты должны быть видны сразу и постоянно, а доступ к выбору определённых пунктов, регулируется с помощью `disabled`. Для реализации таких форм, чаще используют `radio`-кнопки - это нагляднее (что минимизирует ошибки) и оперативнее, чем выпадающие списки.

Comment: Скажите, такое возможно чтобы эти два элемента записывались в бд?

Comment: @dmr да возможно. Это нужно смотреть где и какая БД и форму запроса к базе.

Comment: Сам проект на java, база oracle, к которым прибавляется эти два элемента находятся в txt файлах(т.е Р1.txt, С1.txt, Т1.txt)